# Facing issue in iOS 15 change TabBar item text color

Tags: swift, iphone, ios15

My app build with tab bar controller, i have given custom color for selected and normal tab bar and it’s working fine in iOS 14 and all but in iOS 15 it’s not working properly.
Its showing much lighter grey in iOS 15.

Here’s my code for reference and i have tried many ways but nothing helps me.

```
func updateTabBarItemFont() {
        self.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.tabBarForegroundActive
        self.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
        self.tabBar.isTranslucent = false

        let textStyle = TextStyle.tabBarHeader
        let normal = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: textStyle.font, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.neutralForegroundNormal]
        let selected = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: textStyle.font, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.tabBarForegroundActive]
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
            appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = normal
            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = selected
            self.tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
            UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        } else {
            UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(normal, for: .normal)
            UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(selected, for: .selected)
        }
    }
```

Here's my simulator tabbar screen shot left side is iOS 14 and right side is iOS 15

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSipK.png

I am expecting same as iOS 14 text color in iOS 15

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Have you tired to check in real device ?

Comment: Yes, it’s same issue in real device

Comment: `self.tabBar.standardAppearance` != `UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance`

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming it's not custom tabbar.

Add below line in your `AppDelegate.swift` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

```
UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = {ColorHere}

// In your case
UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = .black
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `AccentColor` on the main app's Assets.xcassets catalog, the `UITabBar` will use that color automatically

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone have issues with that at this point you may found this useful:

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
        tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance
    }
```

If you have a UITabBar Controller with scroll view inside you have to define its behavior at scroll edges. The line above will allow you to set an appearance for those situations.